# Strange results with clang-format options AlwaysBreakAfterReturnType and AfterFunction

Tags: c++, clang-format

clang-format version 9.0.1, applied to C++ code.

The combination of `AlwaysBreakAfterReturnType` and `AfterFunction` is giving me strange results.  The interaction with different options seems quite subtle, so I wonder what I need to do to get my desired result (which is coming).

First, the code being formatted.

```cpp
int foo(int, double);

int bar(int, double) { return 42; }

template <typename T, typename U> XY<T, U> xy1(X, Y y) { return XY<T, U>{}; }

template <typename T, typename U> XY<T, U> xy2(X, Y) { return XY<T, U>{}; }
```

Note that the only difference between the functions `xy1` and `xy2` is that `xy1` provides a name for tis last parameter, while `xy2` does not name any of its paramteres.

Next, the contents of a minimal .clang-format file.

```
---
BasedOnStyle:  LLVM
AlwaysBreakAfterReturnType: TopLevelDefinitions
```

Running clang-format will format the original code as follows.

```cpp
int foo(int, double);

int
bar(int, double) {
  return 42;
}

template <typename T, typename U>
XY<T, U>
xy1(X, Y y) {
  return XY<T, U>{};
}

template <typename T, typename U>
XY<T, U>
xy2(X, Y) {
  return XY<T, U>{};
}
```

However, I want the opening curly brace for the function on its own line, not packed just to the right of the function.

From the docs, I should set `BraceWrapping/AfterFunction` to true, resulting in the following .clang-format file.

```
---
BasedOnStyle:  LLVM
AlwaysBreakAfterReturnType: TopLevelDefinitions
BraceWrapping:
    AfterFunction:   true
BreakBeforeBraces: Custom
```

This results in the following formatting result.

```cpp
int foo(int, double);

int
bar(int, double)
{
  return 42;
}

template <typename T, typename U>
XY<T, U>
xy1(X, Y y)
{
  return XY<T, U>{};
}

template <typename T, typename U> XY<T, U> xy2(X, Y) { return XY<T, U>{}; }
```

This is what I expect, except for the formatting of the function `xy2`, which is just nothing like I'd expect, and not even close to the formatting for `xy1`, which is exactly what I'd expect.

If I go a bit further, and force a break for the template, then I end up with this .clang-format file...

```
---
BasedOnStyle:  LLVM
AlwaysBreakAfterReturnType: TopLevelDefinitions
AlwaysBreakTemplateDeclarations: Yes
BraceWrapping:
    AfterFunction:   true
BreakBeforeBraces: Custom
```

which produces this formatted output.

```cpp
int foo(int, double);

int
bar(int, double)
{
  return 42;
}

template <typename T, typename U>
XY<T, U>
xy1(X, Y y)
{
  return XY<T, U>{};
}

template <typename T, typename U>
XY<T, U> xy2(X, Y)
{
  return XY<T, U>{};
}
```

This is closer, but the formatting for `xy2` completely ignores the request to break after the return type.

The subtle interactions between the different options is q bit confusing, and I have not been able to come up with a way to get what I want, which is basically for functions that have no explicit arguments to get formatted the same as those that have explicit arguments.

Again, note the subtle difference between `xy1` and `xy2`.  `xy1` has at least one named parameter, while `xy2` does not have any named parameters - but neither does `bar`.

Note also that the regular function `bar` does not have any named parameters and yet it is formatted correctly, while the function template `xy2` is still not formatted properly.

What magic combination of options will cause `xy2` to be formatted the same as `xy1` and `bar`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After experimenting a bit myself, I am pretty sure that there is no "magic combination". clang-format seems to have a problem with the missing parameter names.

I opened a bug report: https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=45375

In the meantime:

If you can use C++17, there is a workaround by using the `[[maybe_unused]]` attribute in the second template function:

```
template <typename T, typename U> 
XY<T, U> 
xy2([[maybe_unused]] X x, Y)
{
  return XY<T, U>{};
}
```

(using your last config)

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved in clang-format v14 and above (maybe even 13)

Your issue was migrated to github during the recent move of the LLVM bug tracker

https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/44720